# agm-map control options not working properly

Tags: angular, agm-map

Even if I set the options for agm-maps, I see my options for a small amount of time, then they all disappear. I couldn't understand this behaviour. I created a simple project just to demonstrate the problem in Stackblitz, also I'm going to share my code here.

- ***code sample***

*maps.html:*

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
(mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" 
>
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

*maps.component.ts*

```
  onMapReady(map: any) {
    this.map = map;
    this.map.setOptions({
      mapTypeControl: 'true',
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'hybrid'],
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
      },
      fullscreenControl: true,
      streetViewControl: true
  });
}
```

- ***Stackblitz***

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agm-vvqbao?file=app/app.component.ts

- ***Reference***

> https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/f9c23aa5d166ac7408f13891f6bfa2fc16026b19/packages/core/services/google-maps-types.ts#L431-L444

---

You can see in Stackblitz, my map type controls blink just for a moment in the top left side of the map whenever the maps loads, then disappears for no reason. You probably won't realize in the first try, you can refresh the page while looking at top-left of the map.

Comment: are you using the right api key for google maps ?

Comment: Yes, but should I enable any more API for maptypeId enabling?

Comment: you have to provide API key with the required service(e.g. direction service). i will also suggest you to use googeMaps javascript library instead of agm-map

Comment: I think you are wrong, I use a proper API key, and JS-Maps documentation shows that there's no need for extra API enabling for the key to use map options.

Answer (score 0):

#maps.component.ts#

```
onMapReady(map) {
  map.setOptions({
      mapTypeControl: 'true',
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'hybrid'],
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
      },
      fullscreenControl: true,
      streetViewControl: true
  });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).